# Tensorflow variable Reuse in rnn module

Tags: tensorflow

I'm very perplexed by TF variable reuse. For method rnn, I'm able to find this line of code:

```
   if time > 0: vs.get_variable_scope().reuse_variables()
```

However, for `dynamic_rnn` (the method I need to use), I do not find any reuse_variable line of code, or reuse=True.

All the RNN cells in `rnn_cells` module are initializing using `_linear` method, which does not check if a variable has been created or not, but in LSTM_cell, `_get_concat_variable` does nicely check if a variable's name exists in `graph_key` or not.

So does `dynamic_rnn` not reuse the variable? Should I write a method to explicitly check if a variable is created and return it if it is?

Answer (score 1):

The [dynamic_rnn](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/dynamic_rnn) function has a parameter called scope. So you should create your own scope (using `with tf.variable_scope('scope_name', reuse=True)`) and set it when calling `dynamic_rnn` function.

You can checkout the implementation of [model_with_buckets](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/legacy_seq2seq/python/ops/seq2seq.py#L1205), which reuses the same model for each buckets.